# Use normal coordinates for collision response? (java)

Tags: java

I've finally completed the collision detection, however the collision response is very glitchy (if you try you can go through walls) and that's mainly because I have no information about the collision angle!

I have camPos(x,y,z) coordinates of my camera aswell as the min and max values of model(minX,minY,minZ,maxX,maxY,maxZ).. with a simple test I check if the camPos is interecting the model boundaries:

```
if(cameraX > xMax || cameraX < xMin) {
    collisionX = false;
    collisionY = false;
    collisionZ = false;
} else {                
    collisionX = true;
    System.out.println("collisionX: "+ collisionX); // collision on x is true!
}
```

I have acess to all vertice positions and calculated the min max values of the object to create a BoundingBox.

In order to get the right direction in which I want to push the object I need to know in which direction the nearest face is pointing (left,right,forward,back?)

To find out the angle I thought I could use the normal coordinates which I also have acess to, since they indicate a 90 degree angle to the face, right?

```
console print: //all 'vn' values of cube.obj
    xNormals:0.0
    yNormals:0.0
    zNormals:0.0
    xNormals:0.0
    yNormals:0.0
    zNormals:0.0
    xNormals:1.0
    yNormals:1.0
    zNormals:1.0
    xNormals:0.0
    yNormals:0.0
    zNormals:0.0
    xNormals:-1.0
    yNormals:-1.0
    zNormals:-1.0
    xNormals:0.0
    yNormals:0.0
    zNormals:0.0
```

Basically I want to know how these normal coordinates have to be applied to the min and max values of the object so that I can define all faces of the BoundingBox for example: face A is defined by xMin_a and xMax_a and faces left, face B is defined by xMin_b and xMax_b and faces right and so on..

I hope it's a bit more understandable, it's quite hard to explain..

Comment: Nope, Sorry, I don't get it. :) too vague for me. Receiving a lot of information, but not sure what is what. I guess a little drawing might help.

Comment: Could you clarify what library you're using (e.g. where does `CameraControl` come from), what kind of input you got and tag the question approperiately?

Comment: CameraControl is not important, maybe I have to write it simpler to get the concept around..

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've figured out a way to do it, hope it will help someone else too: I found out how to calculate the faces of a bounding box, it was actually not even that hard and it had absolutely nothing to do with normals.. sorry for the confusion.

As shown in my answer you can calculate the boundingBox of objects with their min/max values.. but you can also define all six faces of the box by extending the check and use a boolean to find out if the respective face collides somewhere:

```
    if(collisionX == true && collisionY == true) {
        if(cameraZ+0.2 > zMin_list.get(posIndex)-0.2 && cameraZ+0.2 < zMin_list.get(posIndex)) {        
            faceA = true;
            System.out.println("faceA = " +faceA + " face a is true!");
        } else {
            faceA = false;
        }
    }
```

You can do this for all six faces where A(Forward), B(Back), C(Left), D(Right), E(Up) and F(Down) will define where the collision direction should be:

If the collision is on Face A, the response will be moving backwards (on z axis minus).. That way you will never be able to glitch through a wall because it will always push you away from the collision area.